# Catalog of lunar crater depths and diameters

Tags: the-moon, planetary-science, reference-request, crater

What is the most recent and comprehensive lunar craters catalog which contains information about their depths as well as diameters?

Comment: I'd be especially interested in small polar craters which are eternally shadowed, the coldest places in the Solar System where water ice might be available. It is challenging for a rover to operate in an area without solar energy. But there maybe are small such craters which a rover can traverse in a matter of hours on battery power?

Comment: @LocalFluff Why not ask that as a separate question? [Shackleton crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shackleton_%28crater%29) fits your requirements, except that it's pretty big so your rovers better be fast if they're to traverse it in a matter of hours. :) Otherwise, small craters tend to be too shallow and charged particle radiation moves too close to its surface even if the source is lateral to it, so electromagnetic interaction prevents long-term embedding of volatiles in topmost regolith.

Answer (score 3):

Lunar crater catalogs usually offer the [latitude, longitude and diameter](http://www.planetary.brown.edu/html_pages/LOLAcraters.html) of the craters as only these can be measured directly.

However, the topography has been used to [determine the depth](http://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/Research/Craters/GoranSalamuniccar_MoonCraters/) in some cases.

[This](https://the-moon.wikispaces.com/Catalogs+of+Lunar+Craters) wiki has a history and list of lunar craters.